# How to stop notification to pop up at exact time in flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications

I am using `awesome_notifications: ^0.6.21` to notify user, as I know that `awesome_notifications` can schedule when we should show up the notification on status bar. Here is the part of the code:

```
Future<void> createWaterReminderNotification(
    NotificationWeekAndTime notificationSchedule) async {
  String localTimeZone =
      await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier();
  String utcTimeZone =
      await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier();
  

  await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
          id: createUniqueId(),
          channelKey: 'scheduled_channel',
          title: 'Notification at every single minute',
          body:
              'This notification was schedule to repeat at every single minute.',
          notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
          bigPicture: 'asset://assets/images/dariSDM-modified.png'),
      schedule: NotificationInterval(
          interval: 60, timeZone: localTimeZone, repeats: true));
 
 
}
```

The thing that I would like to ask is:...So I would like to show notification in each 60 seconds but at the time 15:00:00 I want to stop the notification and start again at 15:20:00, is there a way to do that ?
I have added this code, but still unable to stop at exact time

```
String dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(DateTime.now());
if (dateTime == '2022-07-13 15:00') {
    cancelScheduledNotifications();
  }else ...//fire createWaterReminderNotification
```

Comment: you can check the current time using `DateTime.now()` and it has methods like `isAfter`and `isBefore` to check what it name suggests, is that datetime after/before

Comment: @Pokaboom I have tried it and still the notification always pops up every 60 seconds and unable to stop at exact time

Comment: @Pokaboom I have edited my question, would you like to take a look ?

Comment: if datatime's type is `DateTime` then you are comparing datetime with string which never will be `true` compare it with `DateTime(2022,7,13,15)`

Comment: @Pokaboom I have parsed it ```String dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: I am adding it in my question just now, I am so sorry to make you confused

Comment: I think  parsing and comparing a string is bad practice why not use isAfter and isBefore functions and also first check if really parsed dateTime is ever equals to the string

Comment: because if I use isAfter or isBefore.. I only can make once changes (stop at 15:00:00), while I need to pop up notification again after 15:20:00

Comment: I am courious about what you said earlier, why do you think by comparing string is a bad idea ?

Comment: one thing I noticed is you are using Datetime.now() so I don't think at your place it will be 3 PM so that's why it's not cancelling

Comment: I have printed it to check my local time, and it seems as the same as my current time

Comment: if condition get true and it goes inside the block then it should cancel the notifications as you have call that function or that function have some problem I think